# Node callback args not able to assert instanceof Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm making a few simple functions for oauth, one of which validates that there is a `scope`, `redirectUri`, and `clientId` in its options hash. Additionally, if these don't exist, then it should return `callback(new Error(...))`:

```
function(opts, callback) {
  var scope = opts.scope;
  var clientId = opts.clientId;
  var redirectUri = opts.redirectUri;

  if (!scope) {
    return callback(new Error('No scope provided'));
  }

  ...
}
```

In my tests, I test this by asserting that if no scope is provided, that it should return something of type `Error` and the error should match that description:

```
it('should require a scope', function() {
  var callback = sinon.spy();
  myOauthFunction({}, callback);

  callback.args[0].should.be.an.Error;
  callback.args[0].toString().should.eql('Error: No scope provided');
});
```

However, when I run the tests, I get this error:

`AssertionError: expected [ [Error: No scope provided] ] to be an error`. The second assertion doesn't cause issues, meaning that the argument has a `toString` property, but isn't of type `Error`. I'm kind of confused - why isn't it able to assert it's an `Error`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can maybe see in the output message `args[0]` is actually an array. `args[0]` refers to the arguments of the first call, `args[1]` to the arguments of the second call, etc.

If you want to check the first argument of the first call, you have to do

```
callback.args[0][0].should.be.an.Error;
```

or

```
callback.getCall(0).args[0].should.be.an.Error;
```

More info in the [documentation](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinonspy).

Comment: Oh, okay, I was under the assumption that the `[ ]` wrapping the actual error was just how mocha was displaying the assertion error, especially since `toString()` returns a valid string.

Comment: Yeah, if an array has only one element, the `toString()` return value actually doesn't let you distinguish whether it's an array or not. See: `[new Error('foo')].toString()`.